# `set` generic meaning in CDDL specification

Tags: ledger

I see the `set` generic in [`babbage.cddl`](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/master/eras/babbage/test-suite/cddl-files/babbage.cddl) file but couldn't find it's definition. It seems to be defined as `set<T> = [ * T]`

Answer (score 1):

yes it is an array of `T`

**the only difference is that it is meant to have unique elements**; which is a constraint that you can't express in the CDDL.

You will see ofthen used as

```
set<transaction_input>
```

where `transaction_input` is an utxo reference; it is obvious then that it needs to be an array with unique elements (eg you CAN NOT have the same UTxO spent twice)

Comment: Thanks, is this `set` inbuilt in CDDL specification (RFC 8610), o/w it should be defined somewhere right?

Comment: no `set` is not part of the CDDL spec, that's why it is defined so

Comment: My question was, if it's not part of CDDL spec, then it should be defined somewhere right? Now I know where it is defined, which is [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/master/eras/babbage/test-suite/cddl-files/babbage_extra.cddl#L4). I got earlier misled by the comment at top, _These are definitions ..._ thinking these definitions are for testing purposes but rather, the ones [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/master/eras/babbage/test-suite/cddl-files/mock/extras.cddl) are for testing.

Comment: yeah, you should assume all CDDL files for a single era to be a single file; if they are referring to a `set` then the definition you found is correct